# iOS Simulator refuses to connect to local. hostname

Tags: ios-simulator, local, bonjour

I am working on an iOS app that connects to a web service. For development and testing, we use Bonjour to find servers on the local network, and during sign-in the app offers to connect to one of them instead of the production site.

Since upgrading to El Capitan, I am unable to connect from the Simulator to a web server running on the same Mac. I am able to reproduce this issue using Simulated Mobile Safari and the web server that comes with the stock Python in OS X.

1. Open Terminal, start a web server: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`
2. Open Safari inside the Simulator, enter URL: `http://my-computer-name.local.:8000/`

Simulated Mobile Safari displays "Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server."

Additionally, the following message appears in the Console each time I try to load the URL:

```
assertiond[____]: assertion failed: 15A284 13A340: assertiond + 13207 [28CC4371-F3F9-3578-9436-310B23A2C638]: 0x1
```

Other possibly relevant facts:

- Desktop Safari is able to connect using the URL `http://my-computer-name.local.:8000/`
- Real Mobile Safari (on an iOS device on the same network) is able to connect using the URL `http://my-computer-name.local.:8000/`
- Simulated Mobile Safari is able to connect using the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` (I need it to work with the Bonjour provided hostname, though).
- Simulated Mobile Safari is able to connect to another machine with an URL like `http://other-computer.local.:8000/`
- I'm using Simulator Version 9.0 (SimulatorApp-620 CoreSimulator-179)
- OS X El Capitan 10.11 (15A284)
- Amusingly, searching the web for the UUID 28CC4371-F3F9-3578-9436-310B23A2C638 yields only a handful of job posts. (You can make $15 for fixing this bug!)
- This does not appear to be related to App Transport Security. My app behaves this way when ATS is disabled.

Are you able to reproduce this problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.10.5 and using Xcode 7.0 (7A218) which has pending updates I have not yet installed. On Simulator 9.0 (SimulatorApp-620 CoreSimulator-179) the first try failed, but that may be a red herring. I removed the dot trailing the "local" and it works. I tried it with the dot back in place and it works. My python is 2.7.10

Comment: @FranK. Hmm, yeah, El Capitan seems to be the problem. Also, your Python version is TMI. :-)

Comment: Well, you never know!

Answer (score 4):

I worked the issue around by adding an entry to the local OSX /etc/hosts file:

Append your FQDN after "localhost":

127.0.0.1 localhost mymachine.mydomain.local

Answer (score 1):

One problem that might have been causing this issue is that at some point it seems macOS and Safari started using ipv6 by default, so if you try to navigate to `my-computer-name.local` it will try to access `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`. However `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` only listens on all ipv4 interfaces, using `0.0.0.0`:

```bash
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

So this can lead to connection issues.

This is fixed in python3 (at least 3.10.6 anyway), so this should work better:

```bash
$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.6
$ python3 -m http.server 8000
Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...
```

And a nice feature of ipv6 seems to be that if you listen to all interfaces by using `::` you *also* listen to all ipv4 interfaces, so e.g. `curl 127.0.0.1:8000` also works.

Comment: Interesting! It’s been so long I don’t remember if I solved my problem or what the solution was. I do know I was trying to connect to a Rails app; the IPv4 vs IPv6 theory makes a lot of sense!